# Applying one filter for two panels in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I have two panels in my dashboard and i have applied a filter(select month) in the first panel and the issue i face is the same filter cannot be applied in panel 2.
I don't want to apply same filter in panel 2 again . I want filter in panel 1 to control both the panels.
[image: *enter image description here*]panel 1
[image: Dashboard]panel 2.jpg

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

You can't like this. Your only option is to put the month in the filter bar :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed the two panels into a container and apply the filter to it. This is the way to sinchronize scroll bars between two different grids, for example.

Regards!